# Count most commonly used phrases from a `.txt` file

Tags: python, nltk

I have been trying to use nltk in Python to find the most commonly used phrases from a text file. Here is my code:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import*

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words('comments.txt')

finder.apply_freq_filter(2)
finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 20)
```

[Source: nltk.org](https://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html).

When I input this code, I get nothing. I tried another `.txt` file and it still doesn’t work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The method `BigramCollocationFinder.from_words` expects a list of words. You are giving it a string. But because strings are iterable in Python, this raises no exception but the BigramCollocationFinder happily analyses the characters 'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'e' ... and so on.

So in order to access the content of the text file we have to open it, read it, replace non-character letters (including underscores) and split the resulting text:

```py
import re

import nltk
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = open('sampletext.txt').read()
    text = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', text)

    words = text.split()

    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)

    finder.apply_freq_filter(2)
    r = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 30)

    print(r)
```

For my sample file this leads to

```
[('Juli', 'Monarchie'), ('Makronen', 'Himbeeren'), ('Marschall', 'einst'),
 ('Praktische', 'Ideale'), ('Sachsens', 'Marschall'), ('Venus', 'Anadyomene'), 
('abwesenden', 'Mitglieder'), ('de', 'Dunner'), ('mesdames', 'et'), 
('mode', 'Kavalier'), ('säuerliche', 'Geruch'),
 ('Gottes', 'willen'), ('Lenoir', 'Sergeant'), 
('Spitzen', 'Jabot'), ('beleibte', 'Gattin'), ...]
```

because I happen to have the first chapters of The Buddenbrooks in this text file...

Also note that you have to print the result in order to see anything.